# Is PC2700 SODIMM laptop memory backwards compatible with PC100?

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr, sodimm

Can laptop PC100-133 memory be replaced with PC2700-333 ? Both have 200-pin SODIMM.

Answer (score 5):

No.  PC2700 is DDR (Double Data Rate), whereas PC100 is not.

[Crucial has a handy guide](http://www.crucial.com/support/memory_speeds.aspx) for this information.

Comment: They physically won't fit either. They're different sizes and have different notches near the pins.